# Doesn't fit all content on the page Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Faced a problem. My content does not fit on the page, so I added `SingleChildScrollView` in the `TabBarLibrary`. And wrapped in `Expanded`. As a result, I got scrolling, but also the content size greatly decreased due to `Expanded`, I attached a screenshot below where you can see that an empty space has appeared. How can I make the content appear on the entire page and be able to scroll?

**body**

```
Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TabBarWidget(tabController: _tabController),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          _divider,
          TabBarLibrary(
            tabController: _tabController,
            size: size,
          ),
        ],
      );
```

**TabBarLibrary**

```
return Expanded(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: widget.size.height * .69),
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: widget._tabController,
            children: [
              _tab1(),
              Text('Tab2'),
              Text('Tab3'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**tab1**

```
return Column(
      children: [
        _divider,
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 20),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            //TODO dropdown
            child: Text(
              'DrowDown',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        )
...
```

[image]

**without Expanded**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove `ConstrainedBox`, it limit your **TabBarLibrary** height.

Explain: You have already `Expanded` to determined **height** and a `SingleChildScrollView` inside wich want to fill there **height**, `ConstrainedBox` inside that limit the height, so content will not fill full the scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

try wrap Expanded with SingleChildScrollView

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Expanded(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
```

Comment: You cant put `Expanded` inside `SingleChildScrollView`.